# Is there a way to turn off Drupal flood unblock/control from code?

Tags: module, drupal, blocking, disable, flooding

I would like to turn off the flood unblock/control in Drupal, because the user are blocked after a wrong password.

Attemted all of simple possibilities and disabled it on the admin page, but  every user is blocked after a wrong password.The flood control panel is not enough the solute the problem. I would like to reach that flood control being turning off.

What can i try to remove this module?

Answer (score 0):

Historically, due to lack of a UI, you have needed to empty the flood table directly.
It appears that the latest version of Flood has an Unblock feature (/admin/people/flood-unblock) - https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_control.

Caveat: I have not tested this newest version.

Comment: You still have to empty the floodtable, unless you have installed the Flood module. Flood control is in Drupal core and I cannot find a UI to manage it.